# Google Chrome Preventing Screensaver Activation

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, screensaver

I have had an intermittent problem with the screen saver not activating on Ubuntu 18.04. I have come to realize that this only occurs when Google Chrome is running.  This can happen with it minimized or not.  Chrome can be at my home page or other pages.  I'm not sure it happens 100% of the time with Chrome running.  It does not happen when Firefox is running.  Are there any ides on how to correct this issue?